# How to str split and explode on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to split and explode on multiple columns?
This maybe a basic task but I am drawing a blank currently,

My pandas dataframe:

| Name | Title | City | Country | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Haliey Wells | Data Scientist; Data Analyst; Mathematician | Paris; Suva; Paris | France; FIJI; France | Linkedin |
| Bron Levy | Data Scientist; Data Analyst | HELSINKI; Berlin | Finland; Germany | Kaggle |
| Grace Kalie | Data Analyst; Mathematician | Athens; Budapest | Greece; Hungary | Kaggle |
| Evan James | ML Engineer; Developer | Tokyo; Lima | Japan; Peru | Google |

Currently the code that I have will only work on one column at a time:

```
df2 =(df.set_index(['Name','Source']) #Columns that won't be touched by the index
 .apply(lambda x: x.str.split(';').explode()) #split on the ; [its actually a pipe(|) but for visual purposes I used a ;]
 .reset_index())
```

**Note: the code above generally works for me but I am usually using it on one column.

Desired output:

| Name | Title | City | Country | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Haliey Wells | Data Scientist | Paris | France | Linkedin |
| Haliey Wells | Data Analyst | Suva | Fiji | Linkedin |
| Haliey Wells | Mathematician | Paris | France | Linkedin |
| Bron Levy | Data Scientist | HELSINKI | Finland | Kaggle |
| Bron Levy | Data Analyst | Berlin | Germany | Kaggle |
| Grace Kalie | Data Analyst | Athens | Greece | Kaggle |
| Grace Kalie | Mathematician | Budapest | Hungary | Kaggle |
| Evan James | ML Engineer | Tokyo | Japan | Google |
| Evan James | Developer | Lima | Peru | Google |

Comment: You can explode multi columns with `explode` function, but note that it is possible in pandas 1.3+. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Answer (score 5):

Split first, then do a normal multi-column explode. For example:

```
cols = ['Title', 'City', 'Country']
df.assign(**{c: df[c].str.split('; ') for c in cols}).explode(cols)
```

```
           Name           Title      City  Country    Source
0  Haliey Wells  Data Scientist     Paris   France  Linkedin
0  Haliey Wells    Data Analyst      Suva     FIJI  Linkedin
0  Haliey Wells   Mathematician     Paris   France  Linkedin
1     Bron Levy  Data Scientist  HELSINKI  Finland    Kaggle
1     Bron Levy    Data Analyst    Berlin  Germany    Kaggle
2   Grace Kalie    Data Analyst    Athens   Greece    Kaggle
2   Grace Kalie   Mathematician  Budapest  Hungary    Kaggle
3    Evan James     ML Engineer     Tokyo    Japan    Google
3    Evan James       Developer      Lima     Peru    Google
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way using apply instead of dictionary comprehension and unpacking:

```
df.set_index(['Name', 'Source'])\
  .apply(lambda x: x.str.split(';'))\
  .explode(column=df.columns[1:-1].tolist()).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
            Name    Source            Title        City    Country
0  Haliey Wells   Linkedin   Data Scientist       Paris     France
1  Haliey Wells   Linkedin     Data Analyst        Suva       FIJI
2  Haliey Wells   Linkedin   Mathematician       Paris     France 
3     Bron Levy     Kaggle   Data Scientist    HELSINKI    Finland
4     Bron Levy     Kaggle    Data Analyst      Berlin    Germany 
5   Grace Kalie     Kaggle     Data Analyst      Athens     Greece
6   Grace Kalie     Kaggle   Mathematician    Budapest    Hungary 
7    Evan James     Google      ML Engineer       Tokyo      Japan
8    Evan James     Google       Developer        Lima       Peru
```